# How to fix pyHook typeError?

Tags: python, keylogger, pyhook

I'm making a very simple keylogger, and whenever I type a key, the code works, but it also returns a `TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)`.

It works fine other then that. I've searched online and have come up blank except `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`, but pythoncom is being annoying and giving a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'`. even though I've downloadwed pywin32 (and have tried pypiwin32).

Here is my code:

```py
import pyHook

def keyPress(e):
    if e.Ascii:
        print(chr(e.Ascii))
        if chr(e.Ascii)=="`":
            exit()
keylog = pyHook.HookManager()
keylog.KeyDown = keyPress
keylog.HookKeyboard()
```

Everything work perfectly except for the `TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)` that happens whenever I press a key (except when i press the ` key, which exits without an error).

here is the full error message:

```py
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 147, in main
    handle_tk_events()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 80, in handle_tk_events
    tcl.eval("update")
SystemError: <built-in method eval of _tkinter.tkapp object at 0x0000024ECF6A9030> returned a result with an error set
```

[EDIT]:

pythoncom now works (though I can't figure out why), but the code is still throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyHook required me to return an integer in my function, but I did not return anything, hence the error about expecting an integer while getting NoneType. I just needed to add `return 0`.